# What do the presidents and kings do?

Tags: empire-total-war

What do the presidents and kings do in empire total war? it's just confusing, do they just represent the country? my tsar (King) does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

They have traits which affect how your civilization runs.  For example, King Charles II gives -10 to diplomacy and prestige amongst other (mostly negative) things.

Comment: well mine doesn't have any traits, but he has 2 followers

Comment: If you check the followers they also give some bonus and/or malus to your tsar